# Debugging with a visual debugger - getting lost in WASM?

Tags: runtime, debugging

I'm trying to debug the code with a visual debugger (IntelliJ Idea, but I suspect this question applies generally).  I can get the debugger to stop on break points while the runtime is initialising but, once it's actually building blocks, it won't stop any more.

I suspect the difference is that it's running from the runtime code in the binary while it initialises, but once it's running the chain properly, it's using the chain spec WASM blob which the debugger doesn't recognise. (Unless I'm still misunderstanding that.)

Is there any way that I can force the node to stay with the runtime binary rather than switching?  Or some other way I can debug it? I thought that might be what `--wasm-execution interpreted-i-know-what-i-do` does, but it's not helping.

If it's important, I'm looking at the staking pallet "start new era" code, and I'm not explicitly versioning my runtimes (they all get tagged as "sup" I think).  Alternatively, is it likely that I have a different issue?

Comment: Did you try forcing native execution? `--execution=native`, and ideally the runtime will execute entirely in the native binary rather than the Wasm.

Comment: Ah, that would be the option that I missed - and it works.  Thank you, Shawn.

Answer (score 5):

You can force the runtime to execute in the native binary rather than the Wasm using the `execution` flag:

```
--execution=native
```

From there, you should be able to use the same tracing and debugging tools that you have been using to also peek into the runtime execution.

Answer (score 3):

`lldb` also supports debugging when running the runtime with `wasmtime`. See [here](https://docs.wasmtime.dev/examples-debugging.html) for some more information. But be aware that it probably still has quite some rough edges!